# Cat suddenly peeing inside, usually goes outside somewhere, and is skitterish around us

Tags: cats, behavior

Our 5 year old Female cat, Oreo, has suddenly become afraid of us and will run and hide behind the couch when we come into the room. She is normally friendly and wouldn't do this. She isn't aggressive when you try to pet her, she just tries hiding from, and avoiding your hand. I'm unaware of any of us accidentally hurting her or scaring her.

I've also noticed that she has started urinating inside when she would normally go toilet outside in the garden somewhere. She would scratch at the door to let us know she wants to go outside. She doesn't meow to be let in anymore either.

What's going on? Should we take her to the vet?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any consistent change in a cat's behavior that you can't account for suggests a visit to the vet may be wise. Cats don't like admitting they're uncomfortable.

Comment: Yes, take her to the vet.

Answer (score 3):

### Please take her to the vet!

This could be an indicator for some very serious problems! It could also be an indicator for less serious problems. Either way, a cat wouldn't just do this for no reason. Cats follow routines. There is no apparent reason why your cat would suddenly do this.

Sorry to break it to you, but often cats do this only when they have very serious problems (cancer, something in their urinary tract, other) This is often the #1 warning sign something is wrong with your cat.

**Make a vet visit as soon as possible.** Best of luck to you and your cat.